What is this movie about a time travelling genie?
I faintly recall seeing a movie with one thousand and one nights motif. The twist of this movie is, there is a genie who is banished to 20th century London.
His lamp in old Arabia is connected to TV in his room, he uses it to travel back when he is recalled. Anything that gets through (including the genie) is only visible to the owner of the lamp. I think he brought motorcycle and hunting rifle or similar weapon.
Does anyone have an idea what is the name of that movie? Google didn't help.

Bernard and the Genie by any chance? Don't recall the motorcycle bit, which is why I'm just trying it out as a comment for now :)

@AndrewMartin that doesn't seem to be the movie I was looking for. I don't recall seeing Rowan Atkinson there.

Fair enough. It was a long shot, but I remember the genie travelling back in time at the end with McDonalds Big Macs and things like that.

@AndrewMartin I'll take a look at it, sounds like funny movie :)

I suspect it might be "Les 1001 Nuits" (The 1001 Nights) by Philippe de Broca : 
Trailer : 


IMDB : http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098961/
This is a French movie from the 90s, which some very famous "café-theatre" comedians as the king and genie (respectively Thierry Lhermite and Gerard Jugnot), and the then-relatively-unknown-but-already-gorgeous Caterine Zeta-Jones as Sheherazade (the teenager inside me still vividly remembers watching her fall from a plane and progressively loose all of her clothes... sight ... that, and the horrible pop-corn indigestion I got the first time I watched the movie at home... anyway)

Thanks, it looks like this is exactly the movie I was looking for.
